# Can't add source in Xilinx 14.2

Tags: xilinx-ise

I am currently using ISI Design Suite (Xilinx) 14.2 version in Windows 8.1. I want to Add Source from a location to my main file but whenever I  click on Add Source option, the software Xilinx gets closed every time I do that.

Comment: You could update to 14.7. Xilinx removed many bugs since 14.2. Or you could edit the xise file manually.

Comment: Have you reported the bug to the maintainers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a bug that needs to be reported to the authors of the software.